# LinkedList failing to add LLNodes

Tags: java, linked-list

I am creating a file of ints that is read into a scanner.  The scanner produces a LinkedList of Job that each hold 5 int values.  These Job are then sorted with MergeSort and scheduled.  The resultant schedule will only return one value even if there are hundreds in the file.

I have determined that both Iterable and Mergesort are working correctly.  The bug is somewhere in the creation of the LinkedList.

My code up to the error region is displayed below:

```
public JobSchedule makeSchedule(JobSchedule.Metric metric, Job.JobOrdering ordering){
  Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
  SortableLinkedList<Job> sortable = new SortableLinkedList<Job>();
  LLNode<Job> listptr = sortable.getHead();
  //reads the contents of file into a storage array and...
  // ...inputs the stored values as parameters for Job constructors
  while(s.hasNext()){
    int[] ints = new int[5];
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
       ints[i]=s.nextInt();
    }
```

I verified that it correctly sets the head:

```
    if(sortable.getHead()==null){
       sortable.setHead(new LLNode<Job>(new Job(ints[0],ints[1],
              ints[2],ints[3],ints[4]),null));
       sortable.getHead().getElement().setOrdering(ordering);
       listptr = sortable.getHead();
    }
```

I think this is where the program fails:

```
    else{
       listptr.setNext(new LLNode<Job>(new Job(ints[0],ints[1],
             ints[2],ints[3],ints[4]),null));
       listptr = listptr.getNext();
    }
  }
```

although in my bug testing (placed within the above else block ):

```
 System.out.println("Next:"+ints[0]+" "+ints[1]+" "+ints[2]+" "+ints[3]+" "+ints[4]);
```

It successfully printed upon every iteration.

Any thoughts?

ps. LLNode and LinkedList code:

```
public class LLNode<T>{  
  private T element;
  private LLNode<T> next;


  public LLNode(T element, LLNode<T> next){
    this.element = element;
    this.next = next;
  }

  public T getElement(){
    return this.element;
  }

  public LLNode<T> getNext(){
    return this.next;
  }

  public void setNext(LLNode<T> node){
    this.next=node;
  }
}



public class LinkedList<T>{
  private LLNode<T> head;

  public LinkedList(){
    head = null;
  }

  public LinkedList(LLNode<T> head){
    this.head = head;
  }

  public LLNode<T> getHead(){
    return head;
  }

  public void setHead(LLNode<T> node){
    this.head = node;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this class LLNode in the SE?  I've never heard of it before and a google search doesn't suggest that it is.  Also, what does the error message **say**?

Comment: No its a LinkedList and LLNode created by my professor. I'll edit the question above to include their code.

Comment: And also, I guess its a bug, not an error (still fuzzy on the jargon). So no error message, just bad output from the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A night sleep definitely helped with this problem...

the code block:

```
else{
   listptr.setNext(new LLNode<Job>(new Job(ints[0],ints[1],
         ints[2],ints[3],ints[4]),null));
   listptr = listptr.getNext();
}
```

did not include the setOrdering(ordering) command necessary for the Jobs to be comparable by Merge Sort.

So before:

```
listptr = listptr.getNext();
```

it should read:

```
listptr.getNext().getElement().setOrdering(ordering);
```

Comment: All of the ints read from the Scanner were passed into Jobs, only they were in-comparable Jobs so the final output only included job placed at the head which WAS made comparable by setOrdering()

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code:

```
while(s.hasNext()){
 int[] ints = new int[5];
 for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    ints[i]=s.nextInt();
}
```

creates a 5 int array and if there is more ints in the file it destroys the newly created array and creates a new one. It continues until there are no more int in the file.
 Best case after the while loop finishes you have only one 5 ints array.
Was that your intention?

In other words your ints array stores no more than the last 5 ints from the file. You should either include some sort of addToList(ints) method in the loop or store your 5 ints arrays in an ArrayList and later retrieve them one by one when you create your Jobs and add them to the linked list.

Comment: Also, it's not related to your question but you shouldn't have to create a node when adding item to a linked list. Node creation and all that internal stuff should be hidden and handled inside the list.

Comment: It is as designed for ints[] to destroy/re-create itself upon every iteration of while(s.hasNext()){.

Comment: the next iteration will create a new array from which to create the LinkedList Node LLNode<Job>. the Element of LLNode<Job> being a new Job with the current values of ints[]

Comment: Perhaps it was confusing the issue to break up my code. but the While loop doesn't end until after the end of the else{ conditional where I believe the program is bugging